# Order array of string by input value in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, vue.js

I have a problem, i have this array of strings:

```
[ "Aluminum", "Basic Materials", "Broad Credit", "Broad Market", "Cocoa", "Coffee", "Consumer Cyclicals", "Consumer Non-cyclicals", "Copper", "Corn", "Cotton", "Crude Oil", "Energy", "Extended Market", "Financials", "Freight", "Gasoline", "Global Macro", "Gold", "Grains", "Health Care", "High Dividend Yield", "High Yield", "Industrials", "Investment Grade", "Large Cap", "Lead", "Livestock", "Long AUD, Short USD", "Long CAD, Short USD", "Long CHF, Short USD", "Long CNY, Short USD", "Long EUR, Short USD", "Long Emerging Markets Basket, Short USD", "Long GBP, Short USD", "Long Global Basket, Short USD", "Long INR, Short USD", "Long JPY, Short USD", "Long SEK, Short USD", "Long SGD, Short USD", "Long USD, Short AUD", "Long USD, Short CHF", "Long USD, Short EUR", "Long USD, Short GBP", "Long USD, Short Global Basket", "Long USD, Short JPY", "Long/Short", "Metals", "Micro Cap", "Mid Cap", "Natural Gas", "Nickel", "Palladium", "Platinum", "Real Estate", "Silver", "Small Cap", "Softs", "Soybeans", "Spreads", "Sugar", "Target Outcome", "Target Risk", "Technology", "Telecommunications", "Theme", "Tin", "Total Market", "Utilities", "Volatility", "Wheat" ]
```

I want to create a method that sort this array by a input value inserted, for example if i put in a input "Platinum" the array will show the platinum value first.

Thanks!

Comment: Please also include your current attempt so others can see it and help you debug.

Comment: Use indexOf to find the item, splice to remove it, and unshift to add it to the beginning.

Comment: I will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your array:

```
let search = "Platinum";
arr.sort((x, y) => x == search ? -1 : y == search ? 1 : 0)
```

An example:

```js
let arr = ["Aluminum", "Basic Materials", "Broad Credit", "Broad Market", "Cocoa", "Coffee", "Consumer Cyclicals", "Consumer Non-cyclicals", "Copper", "Corn", "Cotton", "Crude Oil", "Energy", "Extended Market", "Financials", "Freight", "Gasoline", "Global Macro", "Gold", "Grains", "Health Care", "High Dividend Yield", "High Yield", "Industrials", "Investment Grade", "Large Cap", "Lead", "Livestock", "Long AUD, Short USD", "Long CAD, Short USD", "Long CHF, Short USD", "Long CNY, Short USD", "Long EUR, Short USD", "Long Emerging Markets Basket, Short USD", "Long GBP, Short USD", "Long Global Basket, Short USD", "Long INR, Short USD", "Long JPY, Short USD", "Long SEK, Short USD", "Long SGD, Short USD", "Long USD, Short AUD", "Long USD, Short CHF", "Long USD, Short EUR", "Long USD, Short GBP", "Long USD, Short Global Basket", "Long USD, Short JPY", "Long/Short", "Metals", "Micro Cap", "Mid Cap", "Natural Gas", "Nickel", "Palladium", "Platinum", "Real Estate", "Silver", "Small Cap", "Softs", "Soybeans", "Spreads", "Sugar", "Target Outcome", "Target Risk", "Technology", "Telecommunications", "Theme", "Tin", "Total Market", "Utilities", "Volatility", "Wheat"]

let search = "Platinum";
arr.sort((x, y) => x == search ? -1 : y == search ? 1 : 0)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Be aware that this does not actually sort the remainder of the array. It simply moves 'Platinum' to the start of the array and treats all other array entries as equal. So, if the remainder of the array is not pre-sorted, it will not sort it.

Comment: Can also sort remainder of array as follows: `arr.sort((x, y) => x === search ? -1 : y === search ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the response! Could you give the test case? It would be really helpful!

Comment: If the array is not pre-sorted (ignoring 'Platinum'). For example`[ 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze', 'Platinum' ]` will yield `[ 'Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze' ]` rather than `[ 'Platinum', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver' ]`.